# Connect to eduroam over wire: nl80211: Driver does not support authentication/association or connect commands

Tags: wired-networking, wpa-supplicant, ieee802.1x

I have a problem with connecting to **eduroam** network on **wired** connection. I thought that eduroam only works as wireless network, but apparently my institution also uses eduroam 802.1x authentication on wired network. I used the configuration script from cat.eduroam.org (as directed by our admins), which generated a following wpa_supplicant configuration:

```
 network={
   ssid="eduroam"
   key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
   pairwise=CCMP
   group=CCMP TKIP
   eap=TLS
   ca_cert="/home/freyja/cat_installer/ca.pem"
   identity="XXX@XXX"
   subject_match="XXX"
   private_key="/home/freyja/cat_installer/user.p12"
   private_key_passwd="XXX"
 }
```

When I issue:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -ieth0 -c/home/freyja/cat_installer/cat_installer.conf
```

I get an error:

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
nl80211: Driver does not support authentication/association or connect commands
eth0: Failed to initialize driver interface
```

I tried using other driver:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -ieth0 -D wext -c/home/freyja/cat_installer/cat_installer.conf
```

but this also causes errors:

```
ioctl[SIOCSIWMODE]: Operation not supported
ioctl[SIOCGIWRANGE]: Operation not supported
ioctl[SIOCGIWMODE]: Operation not supported
ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not supported
ioctl[SIOCSIWESSID]: Operation not supported
```

I think it's an operating system issue, not fully eduroam-related (I use Debian testing -- stretch). The ethernet card works ok (it connects to standard network). Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an OS problem. You're trying to use Wi-Fi settings with something that's not Wi-Fi.

- First, both nl80211 and wext ("Wireless Extensions") are **Wi-Fi (802.11)** control interfaces – they're used for configuring things like ESSIDs, radio frequencies, and such, none of which exist on a wired connection.

  For Ethernet, use **`-D wired`**, if your version of wpa_supplicant didn't automatically detect it.
- Second, Ethernet doesn't use WPA, so `key_mgmt=WPA-EAP` is wrong. Set it to **`IEEE8021X`**.

  Also remove the WPA "`pairwise=`" and "`group=`" settings.

Comment: This worked. I was trying to solve 'connecting to wired eduroam from console' issue by various means for a long time, thank you very very much!

Comment: Frankly, just use NetworkManager and `nmcli`...

Comment: I can't save private key password in NetworkManager (and I don't want gnome-keyring).

Comment: I'm sure you can save it just fine to `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`.

Comment: No, when I start NetworkManager it 'eats it' from the file. I tried making it read-only, set different settings to prevent this, but then it does not want to run. I must admit this and other things made me 'angry' at this program and I don't want to use it any more.